# How to prevent commits to main from deploying on vercel

Tags: github, vercel

I wanted to know if there is a way to prevent Vercel from deploying direct commits from deploying to production automatically. I don't mind having to click an extra button everytime—is this possible? I saw the [Ignored Build Step](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel) documentation but I dont really understand how to use it or if it even is the right thing to use.

Comment: AFAIK, Vercel doesn't build on `commit`, that wouldn't make much sense, it builds on `push`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the Ignored Build Step feature, do the following

- Create a `script.sh` file in your repo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" == "main"  ]] ; then
  # Don't build
  echo " - Build cancelled"
  exit 0;

else
  # Proceed with the build
    echo "✅ - Build can proceed"
  exit 1;
fi
```

In your Vercel Dashboard, go to your project settings > Git > Ignored Build Step, and write ​`bash script.sh` in the field.

Comment: documentation example here https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel#with-a-script

Answer (score 4):

You can look this https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/60#discussioncomment-114386

go to Settings > Git > Ignored Build Step and enter

```bash
git log -1 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit | grep -w "\[skip deploy\]" && exit 0 || exit 1
```

And you can then skip the deployment by adding `[skip deploy]` to the git commit message.