How to restrict Vercel deployments to only build from the main branch in a Nest.js project?
I've successfully deployed a Nest.js project to Vercel, using Git for the connection. However, I've encountered an issue where Vercel builds the project whenever I push code to any branch. I only want it to build from the main branch.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to restrict Vercel deployments to only trigger builds from the main branch in my Nest.js project?
enter image description here
What I've tried:
Searched online forums for similar issues and solutions.

https://vercel.com/docs/projects/overview#ignored-build-step Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70182062/7976758 but you need to reverse the condition. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvercel%5D+main
